# WordPress WP MVC: MVC Fatal Error: Field "user_id" not found for use in a form input

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using wordpress 4.1 along with WP MVC.

I have 3 three tables that need to be added with a single form input.

Tables: (prefix for all tables: 'wp_w2store_'): manufacturers, addresses, countries, zones.

When I choose to add a 'Manufacturer', i need to add the fields of address table in the same form and along with that i have to retrieve country_name and zone_name from the respective tables, which are also form the fields list of 'Address'.

I dont even get the form inputs in the form and i get this error:

MVC Fatal Error: Field "user_id" not found for use in a form input.

since 'user_id' is the first foreign field to this form, it alone is shown here. if i remove that field, the error will be shifted to next available field and so on.

In the add() function of admin_manufacturers_controller, i have loaded the model 'Address' and set that with all its fields in an array variable, $addresses, as follows:

```
public function add() {

    $this->set_manufacturers();
    $this->set_addresses();
    $this->create_or_save();
}

private function set_addresses() {

    $this->load_model('Address');
    $addresses = $this->Address->find(array('selects' => array('id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                                    'address_1', 'address_2', 'email', 'city', 'zip', 'zone_id', 'country_id',
                                    'phone_1', 'phone_2', 'fax', 'type', 'company', 'tax_number', 'customer_note')));
    $this->set('addresses', $addresses);
}
```

and this is the add.php of manufacturers:

input fields for manufacturers table:

```
<?php echo $this->form->create($model->name); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->belongs_to_dropdown('Address', $addresses, array('style' => 'width: 200px;', 'empty' => true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('enabled');?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('ordering');?>
```

input fields for address table:

```
<h4>Address Fields</h4>
<?php echo $this->form->input('Address.user_id');?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('Address.first_name');?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('Address.last_name');?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('Address.email');?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('Address.address_1');?>
<?php echo $this->form->input('Address.address_2');?>
```

and so on...

[image: screenshot]

Since I dont have enough reputation, i dont have privilege to add an image in the question. Kindly bear.

Any suggestions to rectify this issue is thankfully welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved by adding the code below to the manufacturer model for joining the tables:

```
$manufacturers = $this->Manufacturer->find(array(
                                            'selects'   => array(
                                                    'id','address_id','enabled','ordering','address.*'),
                                            'joins' => array(
                                                        'table' => $this->Address->table,
                                                        'on'    => 'address.id = Manufacturer.address_id',
                                                        'alias' => 'address',
                                                        'type'  => 'LEFT JOIN'
                    )

            )
    );
```

Thanks.